# match every row whose `region_ID=0` with the rows whose `region_ID=1` and calculate a certain distance

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
structure(list(X = c(36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
), Y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), region_ID = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb8fc819ae0>)
```

I want to match every row whose `region_ID=0` with the rows whose `region_ID=1` and calculate

```
dist_to_r1=sqrt((X - i.X)^2 + (Y - i.Y)^2))
```

where `i.` prefix refers to the latter rows. I want to do this using data table syntax.

I have been trying to do this with left joins, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: .Take a look at the `rdist(()` function in the `fields` package.

Comment: (1) Isn't this just a fixed version of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821872/find-the-min-distance-of-each-pixel-to-a-connected-component#70821872)? (2) Why did you include [tag:tidyverse] if you're using a `data.table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a full join, such that each of the six rows in region 0 are joined to the six rows in region 1?.

In that case, you can simply set `allow.cartesian = T`:

```
data[, id:=1][region_ID==0][data[region_ID==1], on ="id", allow.cartesian=T][, dist_to_r1:=sqrt((X-i.X)^2 + (Y-i.Y)^2)][]
```

Edit: OP clarified that only the minimum distance to a point in region 0 is required. In this case, we can do something like this:

```
data[,id:=1]
region0 = data[region_ID==0]

# function that gets the minimum distance between two regions
get_min_dist <- function(region_a, region_b) {
  region_a[region_b, on="id", allow.cartesian=T][,min(sqrt((X-i.X)^2 + (Y-i.Y)^2))]
}

# apply the function above to every region

data[,
     (min_dist_to_zero = get_min_dist(
       region_a = region0,
       region_b = data[region_ID==.BY]
       )),
  by=region_ID]
```

Output:

```
   region_ID min_dist_to_zero
1:         0                0
2:         1               30
```

Comment: But if I use this solution with me actual dataset, the resulting fully-joined data.table would have more than 2ˆ31 rows; which is not allowed by the package. How can I get around that?

Comment: Do you actually need 2^31 "distances".. Or put more simply, in your above example, are you actually interested in the 36 distances implied by your original question?

Comment: no, I only need to find the minimum distance for each `X,Y` with `region_ID=0`

Comment: okay, I adjusted based on your clarification. Hopefully this works for what you need.. Basically, I create a function to take two regions and get min distance, and then apply that function to get distance between every region and the base region (region_ID==0)